# private Field in constructor won't be null, but in method will be null, typescript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, typescript

[here is my source code](https://github.com/JeffreyChan/loma_online_testing)

when i call `api/cateogry/:id` something wrong with *ControllerBase.ts*
in the `findById`-method, `this._service` is null. but in the constructor, `this._service` is not null. I can tell what happen, and I don't know how to fix it. 
please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript's `this` handling is sometimes ignored when calling functions directly rather than executing them on the class object. Instead of passing

```
this._controller.findById`
```

to your router try passing

```
this._controller.findById.bind(this)
```

Comment: thanks, it work now. But I have a other problem. If I change the private _service to protected, gulp will cause error, like Unexpected token; 'constructor, function, accessor or variable' 
why private or public is okay, not protected?

Comment: @jeffreychan can you show a code sample of what you're trying with a before and after? To be in line with Stack Overflow's policies I would recommend posting it as a new question and including code samples in-text rather than linking to them. Feel free to link to that question in a comment here after you've made it.

Answer (score 0):

@Paarth thanks the tip. I am a fresh hand for stackoverflow. I don't know how it works, but I will be noticed next time.
here is my code sameples:

```
class RepositoryBase<T extends IEnityModel> {

private _model: mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document>;

constructor(schemaModel: mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document>) {
    this._model = schemaModel;
}

create(item: T, callback: (error: any, result: any) => void) {
    this._model.create(item, callback);

}

retrieve(callback: (error: any, result: any) => void) {
    this._model.find({}, callback)
}

update(id: string, item: T, callback: (error: any, result: any) => void) {
    this._model.update({ _id: this.toObjectId(id) }, item, callback);

}

remove(id: string, callback: (error: any, result: any) => void) {
    this._model.remove({ _id: this.toObjectId(id) }, (err) => callback(err, null));
}

findById(id: string, callback: (error: any, result: T) => void) {
    this._model.findById(id, callback);
}


private toObjectId(id: string): mongoose.Types.ObjectId {
    return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
}
```

}

as you can see _model is private, and CategoryRepository class extends RepositoryBase, somehow I want access _model in CategoryRepository， so I change private to protected, but it will cause error like this:
[typescript protected error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZuXY.png)

it's so strange for me.